# How do I create an auto timeout for users that redirect to login page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a section to my site which will logout the user and redirect them to the log in page. I want to do this so no user is idle or keep one login secession open for more than 24 hours. How would I create an auto timeout in c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Identity framework? If yes, you will find `IdentityConfig.cs` class in
**`App_Start`** folder. In `ApplicationUserManager` add the following line of code or set the value as per your requirements.

```
manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
```